# logging to ELK stack from karaf

Tags: log4j, elastic-stack, karaf

I've been working on getting an ELK stack setup to have our logs centralized and easier to check, but I'm running into a bit of a snag.

I've modified a few of our java programs to use the socket appender from log4j and it's worked great each time. Now I'm trying to add it to karaf to have all of our karaf logs recorded but it doesn't seem to be working.

I added:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, logstash, osgi:*

# Logstash appender
log4j.appender.logstash=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
log4j.appender.logstash.Port=PORT
log4j.appender.logstash.RemoteHost=HOST
log4j.appender.logstash.ReconnectionDelay=10000
```

to the file in `{karaf_home}/etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg` (with the correct port/host obviously) and then restarted karaf just to make sure (something I read said it would pick up changes automatically but I didn't know if I trusted it so I restarted it anyway) but nothing seems to be making it from karaf to our ELK stack. When I do log:display on the karaf console I see plenty of messages being written to the log, but none in ELK.

Any clue as to why this may not be working for karaf, but is working for other projects using the same appender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at [karaf decanter](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/decanter/latest-1/). It already contains connectors that can be used to send logs to an ELK stack, the `decanter-collector-log` is probably what you are looking for

Comment: unfortunately it not work with 5.* ELK :( elasticsearch-appender not work with new versions